# Specifying Sales/Other Tax component with Payflow

Tags: paypal, payflowlink

We're integrating Payflow Gateway on a ecommerce portal. Considering that customer already has a Payflow account (via Chase), they prefer to go with the same.

After referring to PayPal docs, I'm not sure if tax component can be specified during a Sale (for certain US states and Canada users) and that PayPal displays it as part of Order Summary (Hosted Checkout Pages). Has anyone tried this?

If not, alternately, looks like we can use ExpressCheckout API which internally processes transactions via Payflow and then we can make use of expressive EC api to specify tax details. Any insights on this?

Notes:
In reply to my ticket, PayPal tech support says, hosted checkout pages will not show anything other than total amount. :(

However, I did find references to fields like ALTERNATETAXAMT in their developer guide. I presume, it is processor specific.
Ref: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/

**End Goal (no solution yet):**
User should see sub total, tax and grand total during Order Review.